# How Do I Debug Azure Blob Storage Triggers Offline?

Tags: java, gradle, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

On following a Java [introduction guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij#run-the-project-locally) to Azure Functions I was able to debug locally.

However, the example was using an Http Trigger. When I look at the [blob-storage docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=java) it doesn't say anything about debugging locally or what the `connection` should be.

Is there a way of debugging a blob storage trigger in a Java application locally without a connection to Azure?

e.g. by using a directory or a mock instead of an actual blob storage in Azure?

What would the annotations and config look like to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug blob trigger, then local environment has an alternative plan.

Official offer the storage emulator which is actually based on local sql database 2012. It is not a really azure storage, but it can mock azure storage.

You can first start azure storage emulator and then download blob storage explorer to upload or download. The connection string is `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

For more information, please have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json